# Extract/Split raster dataset by attribute (OBJECTID)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, extract-by-mask

I have a raster dataset with an attribute table generated from a series of image classification (unsupervised) and processing tools (majority filter + boundary clean). The attribute table shows pixels of the classified image, grouped by classification i.e. the "OBJECTID" field.

I want to extract the portion of the image by "OBJECTID" to divide the classified image into separate rasters and ultimately, separate feature classes. e.g. take all pixels with OBJECTID = 2 and copy into new raster or convert to feature class

This has proved somewhat impossible for me so hopefully there's something simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by using the *Spatial Analyst* --> *Extraction* -->*Extract by Attributes Tool* ([see ESRI documentation here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000029000000))

The tool interface is fairly straightforward. For example in the Where Clause option you can build a query with the query builder or just enter `“OBJECTID” = 2` to select a subset where *OBJECTID = 2*

In arcpy it is similar:

```
outRaster = arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttribute(inRas, “OBJECTID = 2”)
outRaster.save(r’C:\test.img’)
```

Additionally if you do not want to have to do the above for each *OBJECTID* and want to go directly to a feature class, you may want to consider using the *Conversion* -->  *From Raster* --> *Raster to Polygon Tool* ([see ESRI documentation here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000008000000))

Use the *OBJECTID* as the Field option to the tool.

At times this will result in a messy polygon feature class with many different polygon’s having the same OBJECTID to clean this up. Run the *Data Management* --> *Generalization* --> *Dissolve Tool* ([see ESRI documentation here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000))

Select *OBJECTID* as the Dissolve Field and check the *Create multipart features* option checkbox.